# Frequency count, grouped by two coumns in R

Tags: r

How to count frequencies occurring in two columns ?
Sample datas :

```
> sample <- dput(df)
structure(list(Nom_xp = c("A1FAA", "A1FAJ", "A1FBB", "A1FJA", 
"A1FJR", "A1FRJ"), GB05.x = c(100L, 98L, NA, 100L, 102L, 98L), 
    GB05.1.x = c(100L, 106L, NA, 100L, 102L, 98L), GB18.x = c(175L, 
    173L, 177L, 177L, 173L, 177L), GB18.1.x = c(177L, 175L, 177L, 
    177L, 177L, 177L)), .Names = c("Nom_xp", "GB05.x", "GB05.1.x", 
"GB18.x", "GB18.1.x"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Counting frequencies :

```
apply(sample[,2:5],2,table)
```

Now, how to combine the count by prefix of columns, or by every two columns ? The expected output, for the four first columns would be a list:

```
$GB05
98 100 102 106
3  4   2   1
$GB18
173 175 177
2   2   8
```

One way to get the count for the first two columns :

```
  table(c(apply(sample[,2:3],2,rbind)))
98 100 102 106 
  3   4   2   1
```

But how to apply this to a whole data.frame ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply `table` to your whole data frame, you can use :

```
table(unlist(sample[,-1]))
```

Which gives :

```
 98 100 102 106 173 175 177 
  3   4   2   1   2   2   8
```

If you want to group by column name prefix, for example the 4th first characters, you can do something like this :

```
cols <- names(sample)[-1]
groups <- unique(substr(cols,0,4))
sapply(groups, function(name) table(unlist(sample[,grepl(paste0("^",name),names(sample))])))
```

Which gives :

```
$GB05

 98 100 102 106 
  3   4   2   1 

$GB18

173 175 177 
  2   2   8
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but the result is not grouped as I expect. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I'll edit it asap.

Comment: Sorry, just edited my answer. Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: Thanks juba, that's precisely it :)

Answer (score 1):

i would've said juba's answer was correct, but given you're looking for something else, perhaps it's this?

```
library(reshape2)

x <- melt( sample[ , 2:5 ] )

table( x[ , c( 'variable' , 'value' ) ] )
```

which gives

```
          value
variable   98 100 102 106 173 175 177
  GB05.x    2   2   1   0   0   0   0
  GB05.1.x  1   2   1   1   0   0   0
  GB18.x    0   0   0   0   2   1   3
  GB18.1.x  0   0   0   0   0   1   5
```

please provide an example of your desired output structure :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer that is sort of a hybrid between Anthony's answer and juba's answer.

The first step is to convert the `data.frame` into a "long" `data.frame`. I generally use `stack` when I can, but you can also do `library(reshape2); df2 <- melt(df)` to get output similar to my `df2` object.

```
df2 <- data.frame(df[1], stack(df[-1]))
head(df2)
#   Nom_xp values    ind
# 1  A1FAA    100 GB05.x
# 2  A1FAJ     98 GB05.x
# 3  A1FBB     NA GB05.x
# 4  A1FJA    100 GB05.x
# 5  A1FJR    102 GB05.x
# 6  A1FRJ     98 GB05.x
```

Next, we need to know the unique values of `ind`. juba did that with `substr`, but I've done it here with `gsub` and a regular expression. We don't need to add that into our `data.frame`; we can call it directly in our other functions. The two functions which immediately come to mind are `by` and `tapply`, and both give you the output you are looking for.

```
by(df2$values, 
   list(ind = gsub("([A-Z0-9]+)\\..*", "\\1", df2$ind)), 
   FUN=table)
# ind: GB05
# 
#  98 100 102 106 
#   3   4   2   1 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# ind: GB18
# 
# 173 175 177 
#   2   2   8 

tapply(df2$values, gsub("([A-Z0-9]+)\\..*", "\\1", df2$ind), FUN = table)
# $GB05
# 
#  98 100 102 106 
#   3   4   2   1 
# 
# $GB18
# 
# 173 175 177 
#   2   2   8
```